# So it says ; HTTP Status 404 - /OpenKM type Status report message /OpenKM description The requested resource is not available. Apache To

Tags: http-status-code-404

So it says ;

HTTP Status 404 - /OpenKM
type Status report
message /OpenKM
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.53

When I try to reach the OpenKM as http://127.0.0.1:8080/OpenKM and also if I even try to get the Tomcat Server page as using http://127.0.0.1:8080, the same error message comes up. Doesn't it strange to get the same "HTTP Status 404 - /OpenKM" error if I'm even trying to access the Tomcat Server Page ?

The "Conf" and "Log" folders are added to the message.

Would you please help me to solve the problem ?

Thanks in advance to all your helps.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
09:57:49,864 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
09:57:49,882 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[D:\ONMS.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\openkm\WEB-INF\classes\logback.xml]] every 60 seconds.
09:57:49,882 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
09:57:49,905 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.JMXConfiguratorAction - begin
09:57:49,914 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.StatusListenerAction - Added status listener of type [ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener]
09:57:49,930 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.TimestampAction - Using current interpretation time, i.e. now, as time reference.
09:57:49,931 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.TimestampAction - Adding property to the context with key="bySecond" and value="2023-09-21" to the LOCAL scope
09:57:49,931 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:57:49,938 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
09:57:49,980 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:57:50,082 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
09:57:50,088 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
09:57:50,140 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
09:57:50,144 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern C:/openkm-6.3.2-community/tomcat/logs/openkm_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log for the active file
09:57:50,149 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@30908d98 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'C:/openkm-6.3.2-community/tomcat/logs/openkm_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log'.
09:57:50,149 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@30908d98 - Roll-over at midnight.
09:57:50,150 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@30908d98 - Setting initial period to Wed Sep 20 16:35:47 IST 2023
09:57:50,170 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.re
09:57:50,170 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
09:57:50,170 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
09:57:50,174 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: C:\openkm-6.3.2-community\tomcat/logs/openkm.log
09:57:50,175 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [C:\openkm-6.3.2-community\tomcat/logs/openkm.log]
09:57:50,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@203ff4cd - Adding [file:/C:/openkm-6.3.2-community/tomcat/logback.xml] to configuration watch list.
09:57:50,180 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Failed to open [file:/C:/openkm-6.3.2-community/tomcat/logback.xml]
09:57:50,180 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
09:57:50,180 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@71472636 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
09:57:55,803 |-WARN in Logger[org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils] - No appenders present in context [default] for logger [org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).